# JQuery error .attr is not a function

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I want to change src of icon used in SharePoint search template.

[image]

But error is coming that .attr is not a function. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Check whether you have referred JQuery.  `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot I see the first line $(".cbs-ItemLink img") is returning HTML as an output but it should return an Object as follows
[image]

If it returns an object then you can use any functions of that object.

There might be 2 reasons for your issue

1. There might be override function for $.
2. $ is not referring your actual jQuery object.

Try to execute with following syntax to get additional information

```
jQuery(".cbs-ItemLink img")
jQuery(".cbs-ItemLink img").attr("src","/")
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.
I tried the same on ready function, DOM was not loaded so I tried it on window.load and this code works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

When jQuery says something (on an object) is not a function, the object itself (your DOM element in this case) is not there

With SP Search, the results HTML is coming in async, so you can't query for something that is not in the DOM yet

To do it right you can monitor DOM changes, but that is senior level JavaScript programming.

- https://davidwalsh.name/dom-events-javascript
- https://davidwalsh.name/mutationobserver-api

---

The easiest way out is using the `window.setTimeout` function to delay execution of your code and every cycle check if your required DOM element exists